# Unable to connect to remote server after: sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www

Tags: ssh, fedora, permissions, sftp, webserver

I tried gaining write permissions to change an HTML file on a remote server that runs Fedora using:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www
```

After entering this line in the terminal connected to the terminal on the server with SSH I am no longer able to connect to the server with FileZilla or establish a new SSH connection with a terminal.

```
Filezilla: Status: Using username "opc". Status: Server refused our key Error: Could not connect to server

SSH: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)
```

I have tried:

```
sudo chmod 755 /var/www/html

sudo chown -R root:root /var/www
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Instead of `/var/www` you didn't by mistake write that as `/var /www` or some other combination that contains a space?

Comment: I appears that somehow, the entie .ssh folder vanished. I now created a new key pair. Created a authorized_keys file withing the .ssh folder. Copied the public key into the authorized keys file. Created a new .key file on my local machine and copied the private key into it. Trying to connect with SSH using the new key still gives me "Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)"

Answer (score 2):

These two things, your messing with `/var/www`-permissions and your `ssh` access should be completely unrelated, unless your user `opc` has a home dir under `/var/www`. If that is the case, go to the home dir of `opc` and

```
chown -r opc .ssh
chmod 600 .ssh/*
chmod 700 .ssh
```

Ssh will not connect if the `.ssh` directory and its contents is owned by a different user  or if `.ssh`'s permissions are wrong.

Next step is to read about permissions for your webserver. Just bluntly changing ownership and/or permissions is a source of trouble and may even become a security exposure.

Comment: I am not sure how it happened, but the ./home/opc/.ssh seems to be missing:

Comment: chown -R opc .ssh
chown: cannot access '.ssh': No such file or directory

Comment: @jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj your `./home/opc/.ssh` path starts with a dot, which means "current directory". So unless you are in `/` it's to be expected that `./home/opc/.ssh` won't exist

Comment: Thank you so much! After recreating all the ssh files after they had vanished it still did not work. Using these 3 lines on the new .ssh folder now fixes the problem.

Comment: @jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj please remember to accept the answer that works best for you. You do this with the tick mark next to the appropriate answer